# How to replace string with the main string with javascript

Tags: javascript

Trying to do something like making html codes usable in my forum. I want to make text hidden when wrapped with the `[hidden]` string and after clicking on a button the original text between the `[hidden]` and `[/hidden]` tags should be shown. I try using

```
var res = str.replace("[hidden]$1[/hidden]", "$1");
```

Comment: Have a look at the documentation to [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and the examples

Comment: PS: Try to ask a question next time instead of just making a statement and showing a broken code ;)

Comment: Also, you might want to use an existing library to support BBCode and the likes instead. No use reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the brackets, `[]`, otherwise they will be interpreted as a [character set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-sets).

```
var string = '[hidden]test[/hidden]';
string = string.replace(/\[hidden\](.*?)\[\/hidden\]/g, '$1');
// "test"
```

Comment: According to your code,what will act as the text collector. What i meant to say is that what did <code>test</code> mean in the above.